# Свининный/свининый

Tags: орфография, лексика, прилагательные

Я знаю, что слово *свиной*, образованное от *свин*, пишется с одной *н*. А что насчёт *свинин(н)ый* – слова, образованного от *свинина*? А думаю, там надо *нн*, так как оно образовано от слова, которое в суффиксе *н* имеет-таки уже-с – *свин-ин-а*.

Comment: https://gufo.me/dict/dal/свининный Похоже, что это слово устарело. В современных словарях его нет.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сегодня лингвисты выделяют только три прилагательных, связанных со словом ["свинья"](https://lingvostranovedcheskiy.academic.ru/453/%D0%A1%D0%92%D0%98%D0%9D%D0%AC%D0%AF):

> Различается употребление прилагательных, образованных от слова свинья. Прилагательные *свинский* и *свинячий* употребляются для характеристики вида или поступков человека и имеют значение — ‘примитивный, грубый’ или ‘непорядочный’ (*свинский вид, свинский поступок*). Вариант *свиной* обычно означает простую принадлежность к свинье (*свиное сало, свиной хвостик, свиная кожа*), хотя выражение *свиное рыло* может употребляться как бранное по отношению к лицу человека, отсюда и пословица — *Со свиным рылом да в калашный ряд*, означающая несоответствие притязаний личности ее возможностям.

В словаре Даля (1863–1866) имеются и другие:
*свиньин, свинкин* — ей принадлежщий;
*свинковый, свиночный* — к свинке относящийся;
*свинина* — свиное мясо вообще, свежина, свиная убоинка; ***свининный**, свининовый* — из свинины приготовленный.

Прилагательное "свининный" также нашлось [в книге](https://books.google.ee/books?id=vwsuEAAAQBAJ&pg=PA393&lpg=PA393&dq=%22%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9%22&source=bl&ots=rqZH-yzIiG&sig=ACfU3U1U0SGX2FvdMA-ACWhNREP42RTObA&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjKsoeqiMOBAxU9HRAIHV01Bb04UBDoAXoECAIQAw#v=onepage&q=%22%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9%22&f=false) "Традиционный костюм народов Пермского края" (А. Черных, Ю. Зверева, И. Русинова, стр. 393):

> **СВИНиННЫЙ.** *Изготовленный из свиной кожи (об обуви)*. Свининной обуви не было...